# High-performance server using libEvent

Tags: c++, libevent

I'm designing a high-performance server (not an HTTP server) and am considering my design options. The server should support a large number of incoming connections (in thousands), and to compile on both windows and linux.

On the windows side, I've implemented a IO Completion Port server, which so far seem to handle the stress. Since the linux demand popped, I now try to find a cross-platform library that gives me a way to use the accept / read events with a thread pool.

So far, libEvent seems like the right choice (something like "Example code: an echo server" in this [link](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref8_listener.html)). But quoting from [another page in the libEvent docs](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref2_eventbase.html):

> If an event_base is set up to use locking, it is safe to access it
>   between multiple threads. Its loop can only be run in a single thread,
>   however. If you want to have multiple threads polling for IO, you need
>   to have an event_base for each thread.

My basic design is to have a thread pool reacting to accept and read events. This quote, if I understand it correctly, says I can't do that.

Does anyone has any experience with high-perf. servers based on libEvent? Should I maybe use a different library?

An example code for such a server would be perfect

Answer (score 6):

`libevent` is the way to go if you want to stay cross-platform.

If you want to be highly efficient, I would recommend platform specific API's like IO completion ports (which you have working on Windows) and [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) in Linux:

Note that libevent uses epoll internally for Linux anyway.

As for your question of mulithreaded design, I hope you are not using one thread to handle each incoming client connection... you would be defeating the purpose of using an event-driven model if you did!  You should design your code so that a handful of client connections are being handled by a single thread, and increase the number of threads as the number of concurrent connections increases.

I would also not do any heavy-duty computational work on the data that clients sends in the threadpool that is doing the IO receiving the data.  I would separate the task of doing network intensive IO and doing any CPU intensive computation into two separate threadpools